# Compact sets and Open sets in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I have from reading up on things understood that open sets in a metric space is not compact. Though I have no clue why. I would like to know why is it they are not compact? I know that a compact set must have a finite subcover for the set but why does it not occure for open sets when it does for closed?

Answer (score 1):

An open set *can* be compact, it just also has to be closed.  For example, $[0,1]$ is open in $[0,1]$ and is compact under the induced topology.

It can be proven that in any Hausdorff space (and therefore in any metric space), a set can only be compact if it is closed (whether or not it is additionally open).

Comment: Would you care to share this proof?

Comment: See the proof given [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Compact_Subspace_of_Hausdorff_Space_is_Closed).

Answer (score 0):

It's not true for general metric spaces (for example, a space with finitely many points). For $\mathbb{R}^n$, however, it's true. Think about the interval $(-1,1)$. It can be covered by open sets of the form $(-1+\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n})$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, ...$

This cover has no finite subcover. You can do the same thing for open balls in higher dimensions.